# Java GUI - JOptionPane/JDialog customization issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, jdialog

So I'm trying to make a simple dialog where the user can input some information... My problem is that I'm trying to make the whole background white; I got MOST of it, but there's a gray line behind the buttons that I don't know how to fix (make white as well). How can I fix it? :(

What it looks like:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Code:

```
JPanel all = new JPanel();
all.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
all.add(names, BorderLayout.NORTH);
all.add(academic, BorderLayout.CENTER);
all.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
all.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20)); //int top, int left, int bottom, int right

Object [] options = {"SAVE", "EXIT"};
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane(all, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, null);
final JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog(null, "Username Information");
jop.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
dialog.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
dialog.setLocation(585, 300);
dialog.setVisible(true);
String choice = (String) jop.getValue();
```

Comment: That's not very easy, you could try using `UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE))`, but I think you'd have to use something more like `UIManager.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE))` - but this effects ALL instances of `JOptionPane`/`JPanel`

Comment: `UIManager.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE))`